# How to delete QHBoxLayout from a form

Tags: qt, qt5

I clear all the existing controls from the form using this code.

```
 QFormLayout *formLayoutFunction;  

  void DeleteExistingControls()
     {
         QLayoutItem *child;
         comboBoxFunctions->blockSignals(true);
         comboBoxFunctions->clear();
         comboBoxFunctions->blockSignals(false);
         while ((child = formLayoutFunction->takeAt(0)) != 0) {     
             delete child->widget();
             delete child;
         }
     }
```

The problem is that after executing this function the widgets of QHBoxLayout are still present.

In the form i have multiple QHBoxLayouts and i want to delete them all.

Comment: You don't delete the layout so what do you expect? See [QWidget::setLayout()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout)

Comment: @chehrlic i want to delete the layout but my current code is not deleting the layout.

Comment: i want to delete the Layout and all the widgets in the layout.

Comment: The layout is not container of the C++ object, it only manages the layout of GUI object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i deleted the widgets of QHboxLayout.

```
while ((child = formLayoutFunction->takeAt(0)) != 0) {
        if (child->layout() != 0)
        {
            QLayout *ly = child->layout();
            QLayoutItem* layoutItem ;
            while (ly->count() != 0){
                layoutItem = ly->takeAt(0);
                delete layoutItem->widget();
                delete layoutItem;
            }
         }
         delete child->widget();
         delete child;
     }
```